# QTableWidgetItem text() property during editing

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I have the following problem with the QTableWidget or QTableWidgetItem:
I would like to analyze the text in the cell during its editing/typing,
for example as a reaction on KeyReleaseEvent.

However the QTableWidgetItem::text() property is changed only AFTER the 
cell editing is finished (focus has left the cell).

How can I overcome such behavior? Of course, it is possible to analyze the
button keys in the KeyReleaseEvent, but with the text() property it would be much easier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to establish a custom QLineEdit as editor through the delegate:

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets>

class LineEdit: public QLineEdit{
public:
    using QLineEdit::QLineEdit;
protected:
    void keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *event) {
        QLineEdit::keyPressEvent(event);
        qDebug() << text();
    }
};

class StyledItemDelegate: public QStyledItemDelegate{
public:
    using QStyledItemDelegate::QStyledItemDelegate;
    QWidget *createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &, const QModelIndex &) const{
        LineEdit *editor = new LineEdit(parent);
        return editor;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTableWidget w(10, 10);
    w.setItemDelegate(new StyledItemDelegate(&w));
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, seems to work!
One more question: how can I get access from the LineEdit to the original TableWidget?